# How to echo meta_key in easy digital downloads receipt (Purchase Confirmation page)

Tags: plugins, php

I was used Easy Digital Downloads plugin for selling services (via "downloads as services" addon). I want to display several custom field of every download items in Easy Digital Downloads receipt(Purchase Confirmation page) by their meta_key.

I was tried following codes, but it seems I need to worked on sessions... Please guide me.

Thanks Regard

```
<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'seat_number', true); ?>
```

and

```
<?php echo get_post_meta( $payment->ID, 'seat_number', true ); ?>
```

and

```
<?php echo strip_tags( esc_html( get_post_meta( absint( $payment->ID ), 'seat_number', true ) ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Are the code snippets you provided displaying anything at all? Where are the IDs coming from?

Comment: My meta_key that used in Meta Field is "seat_number".
do you have experience with EDD?

Thanks for your reply